# Webm to Flac using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, compression, google-speech-api, flac

I am recording audio from HTML and it is getting stored as `.webm` format.
I feeding that audio to google speech api to get the transcript from it.
I found out that `.flac` is lossless so I converted it from webm to flac using `FFMPEG`.
But i am having one doubt, converting audio from webm to flac increases the size of file but if an audio is already lossy with webm format converting to flac will still be lossy because the information is already lost.
Am i wrong with this assumption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Am i wrong with this assumption ?*

No. FLAC conversion will only preserve the data in the source file. Any data lost during original conversion to WebM codec (Opus/vorbis) is gone.

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you tell me what is the correct way to keep the data intact. Any response would be really appreciated.

Comment: When you're recording audio from HTML, you need a lossless compression. Check your browser  API docs for those details, if it's available.